# Show that $\operatorname{span}(\operatorname{span}(M) \cap \operatorname{span}(N)) = \operatorname{span}(M) \cap \operatorname{span}(N)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone guide me through how to prove that
$$\operatorname{span}(\operatorname{span}(M) \cap \operatorname{span}(N)) = \operatorname{span}(M)  \cap \operatorname{span}(N)?$$

I honestly have no idea how I should proceed here...

Cheers

Comment: HInt. The intersection of the two spans is itself a subspace. What is the span of a subspace?

Comment: You need to show (1) $\operatorname{span} M \cap \operatorname{span} N$ is a vector space, and (2) $\operatorname{span} V = V$ for any vector space $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $$\text{Span}\big(\text{Span}(M)\cap \text{Span}(N)\big)$$ is the smallest vector space that contain $\text{Span}(M)\cap \text{Span}(N)$. Since $\text{Span}(M)\cap \text{Span}(N)$ is a vector space, then
$$\text{Span}(M)\cap \text{Span}(N)=\text{Span}\big(\text{Span}(M)\cap \text{Span}(N)\big).$$

Comment: If $V,W$ are to subspace of a same vector space $U$, then $V\cap W$ is a subspace of $U$ (I let you do the proof). @AntonNeundorfer